# Ivy dependency: log4j-api downloaded but log4j-api-java9 not found

Tags: ant, dependency-management, ivy, apache-tika

(I'm using jdk1.8.0_181)

I include a dependency for Apache Tika in my project as follows:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.tika" name="tika-parsers" rev="1.21"/>
```

However, when building, I get an error for one of Tika's dependencies. Specifically:

> :: problems summary ::
>
> :::: WARNINGS
>
> module not found:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api-java9;2.10.0
>
> ==== local: tried
>   C:\Users\Bob\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api-java9\2.10.0\ivys\ivy.xml
>       -- artifact
>   org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api-java9;2.10.0!log4j-api-java9.zip:
>   C:\Users\Bob\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api-java9\2.10.0\zips\log4j-api-java9.zip
>
> ==== shared: tried
>   C:\Users\Bob\.ivy2\shared\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api-java9\2.10.0\ivys\ivy.xml
>       -- artifact
>   org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api-java9;2.10.0!log4j-api-java9.zip:
>   C:\Users\Bob\.ivy2\shared\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api-java9\2.10.0\zips\log4j-api-java9.zip
>
> ==== public: tried
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api-java9/2.10.0/log4j-api-java9-2.10.0.pom
>       -- artifact
>   org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api-java9;2.10.0!log4j-api-java9.zip:
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api-java9/2.10.0/log4j-api-java9-2.10.0.zip
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> ::      UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> ::
>   org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api-java9;2.10.0: not found

If I look at the log during the build, under "resolving dependencies", I see:

> found org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.10.0 in public

As you can see though, there is a discrepancy between the locations. One is in

> log4j-api

and the other is in

> log4f-api-java9

I think this is what's leading to the error, ivy is looking for the dependency in a folder that does not exist (log4j-api-java9). I'm not sure why it's looking there. How can I fix this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467162/log4j2-with-apache-ivy-dependancy-management-unable-to-resolve-log4j-api-java9) appears to address a similar issue but it doesn't have an answer.

Would it be safe to simply exclude the `log4j-api-java9` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I excluded the dependency from my build:

> log4j-api-java9

(I'm not using Java 9 so I feel safe doing this).